# python - explanation of lambda where a parameter is not used in its expression

Tags: python, lambda, backpropagation

## Question

Please help understand what this lambda definition is where parameter `w` does not appears in the expression part.

```
loss_w = lambda w: loss(x, t)    # <---- parameter w is not used in the expression 
gradient(loss_w, W)
```

The loss_w is called as `f(arg)` with only one argument whereas `loss` has two arguments.

```
def gradient(f, arg):
    ...
    fh2: float = f(arg)  # <--- how come 'loss' can take one argument as f(W)?
```

In my understanding, the parameter is to be used in the expression, e.g. `lambda w: w**2`.

- [6.14. Lambdas](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda)

```
lambda_expr        ::=  "lambda" [parameter_list] ":" expression
lambda_expr_nocond ::=  "lambda" [parameter_list] ":" expression_nocond

Lambda expressions (sometimes called lambda forms) are used to create anonymous functions. 
The expression lambda parameters: expression yields a function object. The unnamed object 
behaves like a function object defined with:

def <lambda>(parameters):
    return expression
```

## Code

The code is calculating a derivative of a `loss` function f.

- cs231 [Gradient Checks](https://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-3/#gradcheck)

[image]

```
import numpy as np

W = 0.01 * np.random.randn(2, 3)

def relu(x):
    return np.maximum(0, x)

def loss(x, t):           # <---------- 'loss' function
    global W
    a = relu(np.matmul(X, W.T))
    a:float = a - np.max(a, axis=-1, keepdims=True)
    p:float = np.exp(a) / np.sum(np.exp(a), axis=-1, keepdims=True)

    batch_size = p.shape[0]
    return -np.sum(np.log(p[np.arange(batch_size), t] + 1e-7)) / batch_size


def gradient(f, arg):     # <---------- 'loss' function is passed as f
    h:float = 1e-4 # 0.0001
    grad = np.zeros_like(arg, dtype=float)
    
    it = np.nditer(arg, flags=['multi_index'], op_flags=['readwrite'])
    while not it.finished:
        idx = it.multi_index
        tmp_val = arg[idx]

        # f(x+h)
        arg[idx] = tmp_val + h
        fh1: float = f(arg)     # <--- why loss(x, t) can only take one argument?

        # f(x-h)
        arg[idx] = tmp_val - h 
        fh2: float = f(arg) 
        grad[idx] = (fh1 - fh2) / (2*h)
        
        arg[idx] = tmp_val
        it.iternext()   
        
    return grad
```

```
def numerical_gradient(x, t):
    t = t.reshape(1, t.size) if t.ndim == 1 else t
    x = x.reshape(1, y.size) if x.ndim == 1 else x
       

    loss_w = lambda w: loss(x, t)  # <----- What is this w?

    global W
    return gradient(loss_w, W)
```

The original code is [two_layer_net.py](https://github.com/oreilly-japan/deep-learning-from-scratch/blob/master/ch05/two_layer_net.py#L49) which implements the cs231.

---

## Update

Now I am convinced that `W` is a redundant parameter. The original intent would have been explicit with `f(x)` hence trying to pass the weight parameter `W` as `f(W)`. Perhaps it should have been `lambda w: loss(w, t)`.

Answer (score 0):

In general you could write a lambda function which doesn't use its parameter at all.  For example:

```
>>> a = lambda x,y:1+2
>>> a(1,2)
3
>>> a(None,4)
3
>>> a()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: <lambda>() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'x' and 'y'
```

In your question you've asked "why loss(x, t) can only take one argument?". Because lambda function takes only one argument and doesn't even use it and gives to `loss` method other arguments.